# Regex not matching my string

Tags: java

I have this pattern I'm trying to match against a string but it's not working and I'm not sure why. Here's what I have:

```
Pattern wDecimal = Pattern.compile("((\\d+)\\.(\\d+))\\'"); // 12.5'
Matcher mwDecimal = wDecimal.matcher(line);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = "";
    System.out.println("Please input your Architectural String: ");
    boolean flag = false;
    while(!flag) {
        line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(wDash.matcher(line).matches());
        if(mwDecimal.find()) {
            formatwDecimal(line, mwDecimal);
        }
        else System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

I've tried testing using .find() and .matches() but they both return false when the input is `12.5'` 
Any idea why it's not working? Thanks!

Here's the code for the function call if needed:

```
    public static void formatwDecimal(String s1, Matcher m) {
    if (m.find()) {
        double feet = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        int feetPart = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        double inchesPart = Double.parseDouble(m.group(3));
        double output = feet * 12;
        System.out.print(s1 + " | " + "Meaning: " + feetPart + " Feet and " + f.format((inchesPart * 0.1) * 12)
                + " inches. | " + Double.parseDouble(g.format(output)) + " decimal inches.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is value of `line` when the `mwDecimal` field initializer is executed? Updating `line` in your code does **not** change the `Matcher`. You then print `wDash.matcher(line).matches()`, which is a new matcher, so it may print `true`, but you don't update the `mwDecimal` matcher, so it still return `false`. And remember, each call to `find` forwards the matcher to the **next** match. Calling `find` twice, like you do, will only process second match, and since you like only have one match in the `line`, your code fails there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output it is clear that the regular expression is wrong.
The below reg ex will work for you

```
Pattern wDecimal = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+[.][\\d+][\'])"); // 12.5'
```